# RxJava observe multiple observers in single subscriber

Tags: android, sonarqube, rx-java, rx-java2, sonarlint

**Code**

```
Author author = baseRealm.where(Author.class).equalTo("id", mId).findFirst();

public boolean checkGlobalSyncStatus(Author author, List<Books> mBooks) {

    final boolean[] isJobSynchronized = {false};

    Observable.fromIterable(mBooks)
            .filter(Books::isChanged)
            .doOnNext(book -> isJobSynchronized[0] = true)
            .just(author)
            .flatMapIterable(Author::getAllBooks)
            .filter(MyBook::isChanged)
            .doOnNext(mBook -> isJobSynchronized[0] = true)
            .just(author)
            .flatMapIterable(Author::getAllWriters)
            .filter(Writers::isChanged)
            .doOnNext(jobPage -> isJobSynchronized[0] = true)
            .subscribe();

    return isJobSynchronized[0];
}
```

**Problem**

`fromIterable(mBooks)` is called from *static-reference* `Observable` **BUT** `just(author)` is called from *instance-reference*.

I only want to get this operation done in single query. I can make different observable for each and perform desired operation but that would be lengthy.

**Why?**

By doing so, `SonarQube` is giving me unsuccessful check and forcing me to remove *instance-reference*.

Any alternatives will be appreciated.

---

[image: Lint analysis]

Comment: please post the calling func of `checkGlobalSyncStatus(author) ` .. and the declaration statement of author var..there

Comment: Its a simple Java pojo class which extends RealmObject.

Comment: `static Author author =...` then `checkGlobalSyncStatus(author);` isnt working??

Comment: @SantanuSur please check updated question. The issue is `Observable.fromIterable` is alright but I have added `.just()` static method call without reference. that is the issue.

Comment: Why did you add `.just`? Those static method calls throw away all things above and start a new sequence with only `author`. Second, why are you using RxJava for a clearly synchronous check?

Comment: @akarnokd Yes, I know. That's why i am performing operation in `doOnNext` to check for filtered objects. Second, just to avoid nested loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to use RxJava here, however, the proper combination of operators would be as follows:

```
Author author = baseRealm.where(Author.class).equalTo("id", mId).findFirst();

public boolean checkGlobalSyncStatus(Author author, List<Books> mBooks) {

    return Single.concat(
                Observable.fromIterable(mBooks)
                .any(Books::isChanged)
                , // ---------------------------------------------
                Observable.fromIterable(author.getAllBooks)
                .any(MyBook::isChanged)
                , // ---------------------------------------------
                Observable.fromIterable(author.getAllWriters)
                .any(Writers::isChanged)
           )
           .any(bool -> bool)
           .blockingGet();
}
```

Comment: Technically, That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `just()` as an operator when it is really an observable. It looks like your intention is to use the passed in `author` to make a series of queries, and then check that any of the books associated with the author have "changed".

Additionally, you are trying to return a boolean value that likely has not been set by the time the return occurs. You may need to block and wait for the observer chain to finish if you want the value. More likely, you want the observer chain to finish if *any* book has changed.

Additionally, the series of steps where you set the flag to true come down to setting the flag to `true` the first time.

Instead of `just()`, use `map()` to rebind the original author into the observer chain. Use the `toBlocking()` operator to make the process synchronous.

```
Observable.fromIterable(mBooks)
        .filter(Books::isChanged)
        .toBlocking()
        .subscribe( ignored -> isJobSynchronized[0] = true );

return isJobSynchronized[0];
```

Since the (presumably) asynchronous queries are no longer necessary to compute the value, remove RxJava:

```
return mBooks.stream()
         .filter(Books::isChanged)
         .anyMatch();
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct. I am making series of queries synchronously. more specifically just to get rid of nested loops. meanwhile, stream API is good to go but that call requires **Android N**.